Running a PL/SQL update statement from a variable
I am trying to use an update statement in a cursor but values like the table name (and column names) are changing with every record fetched from the cursor. I am storing the table name and column names in a table and use these as parameters for the update statement. With each loop through the cursor, I am initializing a variable with the update statement.
My question is, how do I execute an update statement which is stored in a variable. I want to execute the update statement with each loop in the cursor.
Thanks.
I have been initializing a variable with the update statement.
lv_update_statement := 'update scpomgr.'|| lv_table_name || ' set ' || lv_param_name || ' = ' || lv_param_value || ' where item = ' || lv_item || ' and loc = ' || lv_loc || ';';

Use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and string concatenation for the identifiers and bind variables for the values (and do not include the ; terminator in the statement):
BEGIN
  FOR rw IN (
    SELECT table_name,
           param_name,
           param_value,
           item_value,
           loc_value
    FROM   your_table
  )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'update scpomgr.'|| DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(rw.table_name)
                  || ' set ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(rw.param_name) || ' = :1'
                  || ' where item = :2'
                  || ' and   loc = :3'
      USING rw.param_value, rw.item_value, rw.loc_value;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE your_table (table_name, param_name, param_value, item_value, loc_value) AS
SELECT 'A', 'PARAM', 9, 2, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE a (param, item, loc) AS
SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 5, 6 FROM DUAL;

Then after executing the PL/SQL block, the table contains:



PARAM
ITEM
LOC




9
2
3


4
5
6



fiddle
